# laravel php artisan config:clear causes jquery and PhpDebugBar to become undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, config, phpdebugbar

When I run php artisan config:clear my application can no longer log in and all pages have the follow errors.

```
127.0.0.1/:1 Refused to apply style from 'https://127.0.0.1:8443/_debugbar/assets/stylesheets?v=1608300097&theme=auto' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'https://127.0.0.1:8443/_debugbar/assets/javascript?v=1608300097' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
(index):21 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at (index):21
(anonymous) @ (index):21
(index):295 Uncaught ReferenceError: PhpDebugBar is not defined
    at (index):295
```

When I run php artisan config:cache everything works again.

Comment: sounds like you have some type of error being returned, check your logs

Comment: No errors in the log, unfortunately.

Comment: Check your js include and generated HTML